# PHP object-oriented access to a method and issues with $this

Tags: php

I have been working with Yii framework for a while, but know I am trying to work on my own minimalistic framework based on MVC architecture. 
Let's just say that I have a parent model **ModelCore** which extends all other models (mentioned PageModel also). It has defined method:

```
public function find( $condition ){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM {$this->table()} WHERE {$condition} LIMIT 1";
    // executing query and returning the result
}
```

And I am stuck at the point when I want to call this method from other class (**URLresolver**) this way:

```
//...
elseif ( PageModel::find("`url` = '{$bit}'") != NULL ) {
//...
```

The scripts ends with fatal error: *Call to undefined method URLresolver::table()*

If someone can explain me how theese things work in PHP and how can I easily access a method I would be grateful.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `::` it refers to a static function. If you created an object, you have to do it like:

```
$obj = new PageModel( );
$obj->find(" YOUR QUERY ");

public function find( $q ){ }
```

If you have a static method (in these functions $this does not reffer to the object, because you did not create a `new` object.

```
PageModel::find( $q ){}

public static function find ( $q ){ }
```

Comment: Quite helpful. I didn't know that :: refers to a static function. I will try to handle it other way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The scripts ends with fatal error: Call to undefined method `URLresolver::table()`

Find where you are calling `table()` function which seems to dont exist,and... is it a `static` method? Otherway you dont need the `::` notation, but `->`

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty self-explanatory: the `URLresolver` class doesn't implement (or inherit) a method named `table`. Are you sure you didn't mean to call a *property* with that name?